# Avoid Bootstrap lightbox scrollbars from appearing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the [Bootstrap Lightbox](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#single-image) code from Ashley White.

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});
```

```html
<!-- css -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML -->

<a href="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273528034c2cfe590178ac6657a" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Instrument Soundtrack by Fugazi">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/250.jpg?image=250" class="img-fluid">
</a>

<!-- javascript -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

For some reason when I click the smaller image to open the lightbox image, the modal window contains scroll bars.

I have [reviewed the docs](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/) and have also tested setting the max with via `data-max-width="250"` for example, but doing so still results in the scroll bars being visible.

I wondered if there is a way for the image to fit without the scrollbars appearing?

Comment: Did you try to set the modal window container overflow: hidden?

Comment: Hi you solve with img { max-width: 100%; }